# GUI and extract from excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pysimplegui

Please help me with this code. Basically what I am trying to do is create a userform to fill in a template (with name of assessor, date, role of assessor etc), then extract the rest of the data for said template from an excel sheet which will contain most of the data.

I have set up my template and I have managed to create the user form. I am having problems producing the template and keep getting an error on line 50 of code:

I am not very experienced with Python (using Python 3.10) and have been learning from youtube but a fix would make work so much easier.

Please help!!!!

```
#Import Packages
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import pandas as pd

#Define Paths

document_path = Path(__file__).parent / "Template.docx"
doc = DocxTemplate(document_path)
base_dir = Path(__file__).parent
excel_path = base_dir / "excel_data.xlsx"
output_dir = base_dir / "OUTPUT"
# Create output folder for the word documents
output_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# Convert Excel sheet to pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name="Sheet1")
#Layout of user form:

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Project:"), sg.Input(key="Project", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("Part Number:"), sg.Input(key="Part_Number", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("Identity:"), sg.Input(key="Assessment_Form_Number", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("Assessed By:"), sg.Input(key="Assessed_By", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("Assigned Role:"), sg.Input(key="Assigned_Role", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("Date:"), sg.Input(key="Date", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Button("Create Hazard Assessment Form(s)"), sg.Exit()],
]

window = sg.Window("Hazard Assessment Form Generator", layout, element_justification="right")

    #Conditions:

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    df1 = df.to_dict()
    valuesnew = (values | df1)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
    if event == "Create Hazard Assessment Form(s)":
        for record in valuesnew:
            doc.render(valuesnew)
            output_path = Path(__file__).parent / f"Folder-{record['Hazard_ID']}.docx"
            doc.save(output_path)
            sg.popup("File saved", f"File has been saved here: {output_path}")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\am\PycharmProjects\AutomationTest\Test.py", line 50, in <module>
    output_path = Path(__file__).parent / f"DEV357-{record['Hazard_ID']}.docx"
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Maybe you can reduce your code to only: (1) What value for `valuesnew` now (2) Expectation, like get which item in `valuesnew`, then no library required and maybe only 5-line code to ask the question, or you will know the answer by yourself immediately.

Comment: `record` is a string instead of a dictionary? Try adding `print(record)` at the top of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a dictionary produces the keys:

```
In [1]: d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4};

In [2]: [k for k in d]
Out[2]: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

It seems like your the keys of the dictionary `valuesnew` are strings, hence the error.

Your question doesn't show the structure of `valuesnew`.
But based on the other code I suspect it is a nested dictionary, that is a `dict` within a `dict`.
In that case you should iterate over the *values* of `valuesnew`:

```
for record in valuesnew.values():
```

**Edit1**

Try printing out `valuesnew`. Or save it as a JSON file.
You need to look at the shape of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still getting the same error. Maybe I have not merged the dictionaries correctly I don't know :( any further info would be greatly appreciated –

Comment: @AM96 See updated answer.

Comment: Roland you are right it is a nested dictionary `{ 'Hazard_Category': {0: 'Hazard Category 1', 1: 'Hazard Category 2', 2: 'Hazard Category 3', 3: 'Hazard Category 4', 4: 'Hazard Category 5'}, 'Hazard': {0: 'Hazard 1', 1: 'Hazard 2', 2: 'Hazard 3', 3: 'Hazard 4', 4: 'Hazard 5'}` even when i use for record in values new.values (). Now I am still getting same error code `TypeError: keywords must be strings`

Comment: @AM96 You are still getting a `TypeError`, but it is a *different one*. :-) Can you **edit** your question and update it with the changed code and the *complete* new traceback?